# Understanding the authorization flow with Google Drive and Google Play Services

Tags: google-drive-api, google-play-services

I have gone through Quickstart with Google Drive and I have also used Google Play Services. The docs for Google Drive outline the process of how the authorization flow works. The docs also indicate that developers should not use Drive initiated authorization although it appears that the Quickstart sample app does exactly that. I am left with the impression that Google prefers that the developer handle all the details of authorization.

Yet after trying out sample code that uses Google Play Services (but not for Google Drive), I am left with the impression that Google wants developers to use Google Play Services to handle all the authorization. It seems that Google Play Services simplify the authorization process significantly. Although the docs don't say this, I found elsewhere online that GoogleAuthUtil.getToken manages how access and refresh tokens are retrieved, especially after they expire.

Basically, the issue I am struggling with to understand is whether the Google Drive docs for the API are out of date and Google wants us to rely upon Google Play Services. There seems to be a lot of complexity in the Google Drive authorization process that Google Play Services has eliminated. At the same time, the docs for Google Drive API has been available for over half a year, so it makes me question why Google hasn't updated these docs to show any reflection on how Google Play Services are used with it.

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach for authorization on Android is using Google Play Services. The Android quickstart guide on the Google Drive SDK documentation covers exactly that:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: It doesn't cover that at all. If you read the docs, all you are told about Google Play Services is to install it. Aside from that, there is zero mention of how one integrates Google Play Services. In fact, there is no mention at all that Google Play Services handles all the token management. The Google Drive docs are very lacking.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Drive docs are out of date and Google should really update them. Retrieving tokens and authenticating users should be done using Google Play Services. The only thing you should be using the Google Drive API for is accessing the Google Drive service. Google Play Services handles all the details of authenticating users, retrieving access and refresh tokens and handling all the errors that can arise.